# SQL Server query for a VB dropdown list

Tags: sql, list, dynamic, populate

I am working on administering an "erp type" VB program which is running on SQL Server 2008 R2. This program allows users to have a card for each file stored in its vault. Those cards are built into administration tools and u can add elements like comboboxes, dropdownlists etc. You can also add an SQL query into a dropdown list. So i have these 2 tables in SQL Server database:

`USERS`:

```
USERID / NAME / USERGROUPID
```

and

`USERGROUPS`:

```
USERGROUPID / USERGROUPNAME
```

I want to add 2 dropdown lists in my cards connected to SQL with query but i want the 2nd one to be connected with the selection from the 1st one. The 1st one asks for the usergroup name and the 2nd one asks for the name in the previously selected usergroup.

I found out that the 1st dropdown list should be:

```
SELECT USERGROUPNAME 
FROM USERGROUPS
```

The 2nd one should be like:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM USERS
INNER JOIN USERGROUPS ON USERS.USERGROUPSID = (USERGROUPS.USERGROUPID FROM PREVIOUS SELECTION)
```

How can I modify the 2nd query in order to get the data I need?

Comment: Previous selection is the whole table so why not `ON USERS.USERGROUPSID=USERGROUPS.USERGROUPID`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query for second one. It will select all NAME that matches with the GroupName you selected

```
SELECT NAME
FROM USERS usrs
INNER JOIN USERGROUPS usrgrps ON usrs.USERGROUPSID=usrgrps.USERGROUPID
WHERE usrgrps.USERGROUPNAME='VALUE FROM DROPDOWN 1';
```

Comment: I know i have to add the value there but do i have to declare it as a variable first ? if yes how i can do it? do i need a stored procedure for this?

Comment: Yes if you need that user selected value(from dropdown) to be given to the query you need an variable. You dont need stored procedure. You can have a function instead. You can pass the variable to that function as parameter and inside the function you do all the stuff.